# How to lookup a column value in another column and display a different column

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports. In our tables we have members and clients. Members refer clients to our business.  I am trying to display the customer name, and if they have a referring member display the referring members customer name as well. Since they are in the same table how can I do this?

In the scenario below Jake is the client with Mike being the referring member. The sequence number and referring member columns tie them together.

Seq Number ---  Customer Name ---------Referring Member

4356 -----------------Mike  -----------------------------      0

7286   ----------------      Jake     --------------------------       4356

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1ZoL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Crystal, Database Expert, bring in the Customer Table table into the report a second time. Give it an Alias of "Member". Join the Customer table to the "Member" table on Customer.Referring Member = Member.Seq Number.

Comment: So that worked beautifully. Now the issue I am running into is, since members have a 0 in the referring member field. The crystal report is sorting them out.  For a sale a member or a client can buy. If a member can buy I'd like to show the member as well and if a client buys i'd like to show the member.

Comment: I tried a formula.  If customer.referringmember=0 then customer.custname else member.custname

Comment: full outer join on the link between customer.referring member and member.seq.number fixed it! Thank you.

Comment: No need for full outer join. Just a LEFT Outer join (from Customer to Member).